# Autoit script on remote machine

Tags: azure, automation, autoit, remote-desktop, rdp

Currently I am running a jarfile from my CENTOS machine that takes parameters to make a connection to azure Windows VM using WINRM.

I get the sessionID of RDP and using psexec I execute my autoit script on the RDP sessionID (this assumes that I need to have already a RDP connection established).

```
psexec.exe -i 2 "C:\Program Files\AutoIt3\AutoIt3.exe" "C:\Users\admin\runNotepad.au3"
```

The script runs perfectly when I have a RDP session maximized/opened. If I minimize the RDP window some commands do not work, as for example the Send command.

How can I guarantee, taking my setup, that a session with GUI is opened and how can I bypass(if there is a way) the constraint of having the RDP window maximized in order to run the test?

I can also change my architecture if required (apart from the CENTOS machine).

Thanks

Comment: Not really duplicate. But to give more info:

I can now use tscon to connect to the session ID of the RDP when I close the RDP window, the problem with this, is that it need to be at least have the RDP connection established once, meaning if I reboot I need to login via RDP at least one time.

Also, I am struggling with opening the RDP connection via CentOS without no GUI. I am treying to find solution with winrm opening RDP on localhost perhaps.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25298491/4157124).