# Access window in absence of graphical interface

Tags: c#, windows, iis, autoit-c#-wrapper

Creating a monitoring solution for an ERP in C#, the goal is to check when an application is not available anymore. The only way is to open its window; it will not open and shows an error pop up if so.

My code works, but once published on the IIS server it does not work anymore. The window does not open and the ERP is apparently opened in the background (no graphical interface). The IIS server is set to use my user account.

Can someone explain what I did wrong or advice how to solve this problem? Task Manager Screenshot:

[image]

My code :

```
private static bool IsDown(this NST nstObject)
    {
        bool L_Break_Loop = false;

        Console.WriteLine("Country being processed : " + nstObject.Trigram);

        int L_Launcher_Handle = AutoItX.RunAs("MYUSERID", "COMPANYDOMAIN", "PASSWORD", AutoItX.SW_SHOW, OutputFileLocation + "//" + nstObject.Trigram + ".cmd", "");

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(OutputFileLocation + "//ProcessNav.txt", "Worked : " + L_Launcher_Handle.ToString());

        AutoItX.WinGetHandle("Microsoft Dynamics NAV"); // Getting Navision splash screen

        while (AutoItX.WinExists("Microsoft Dynamics NAV") == 0)
        {
            AutoItX.WinGetHandle("Microsoft Dynamics NAV");
        }

        DateTime L_DateTime_Window_Appeared = DateTime.Now;

        while (!L_Break_Loop)
        {
            AutoItX.WinGetHandle("Microsoft Dynamics NAV"); // Getting Navision splash screen

            if (DateTime.Now > L_DateTime_Window_Appeared.AddSeconds(60) && AutoItX.WinExists("Role Center") != 1) // If timeout reached + role center doesn't exist
            {
                L_Break_Loop = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (AutoItX.WinExists("Role Center") == 1) // If role center appeared
            {
                L_Break_Loop = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (AutoItX.WinExists("Role Center") == 1) // Role Center found
        {
            Close_Window("Role Center");

            Console.WriteLine("NST status : UP");
            return false;
        }
        else if (AutoItX.WinExists("Role Center") != 1) // Role Center not found
        {
            Close_Window("Microsoft Dynamics NAV"); // In case of NST restarting while script running => NAV opens last moment but script doesn't catch it.

            Close_Window("Role Center");

            Close_Window("Select Server"); //Closing the select servers page

            Console.WriteLine("NST status : DOWN");
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: [Using PsExec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25298491/4157124) possibly.

Comment: Hi, I tried but it didn't worked out. So at the end the solution I found was to create a node.js webserver. Since I could use autoit as well, I translated in javascript the code above. By calling the node.js server from the WS hosted on the IIS it works as a charm.